# Why does a bike skids on the sand?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, friction, everyday-life

Whats the theory behind bike skidding on the sand?
Is it related to friction and if then why it skids. Is that the
sand has more friction if so then pedaling should be difficult rather than skidding.

Comment: Why would more friction make pedaling difficult?

Answer (score 1):

loose sand has no shear strength. This is why bike wheels skid on sand: the sand adheres to the tire, but that sand shears loose from the rest of the sand. Then you fall down go BOOM.